# Flume not accepting keywords for Twitter stream

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-twitter

a Hadoop neophyte here, using this tutorial: https://acadgild.com/blog/streaming-twitter-data-using-flume/ to capture tweets. Here is my flume.conf file:

```
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey=xxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret=xxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken=xxxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret=xxxx

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords= #canpoli

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel=MemChannel
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity=10000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type=hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path=hdfs:/xxxx/user/flume/tweets
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType=DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeformat=Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize=1000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize=0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount=10000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval=600

TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type=memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity=10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity=1000

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel`
```

It streams tweets fine, it saves into my desired directory correctly, but it seems to be streaming everything without filtering for my keyword. I get tweets from all over the world except with that hashtag.

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

First, it's accepting all hashtags because you gave an empty list.

`#` character is a comment, so everything after the equals is seen as ignored. At least I think that's how it is parsed.

You linked to a site that doesn't use the `#`, so I would follow that tutorial until it worked.

Secondly, that source is considered experimental, and doesn't seem to mention keywords.

https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#twitter-1-firehose-source-experimental

Your code looks almost exactly like this example from Cloudera that includes comments in the config and has keywords, which if you check, there's a different source class.

```
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
```

https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example/blob/master/flume-sources/flume.conf

You need to download that java code there, package it to a JAR, and place it in the Flume lib directory

Comment: I remove the hashtag and I get the same result. All the tweets that are being ingested do not contain any of the keywords.

Comment: What if you run the example provided?

Comment: The exact same thing happens.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the correct config? What command are you using?

Comment: flume-ng agent -n TwitterAgent -f /etc/flume/conf/flume.conf (where the file is located)

And I did double check, I am running the same the same config that I am editing.

Comment: Hi, I've been playing with this for a few days. No luck and no change. Using 'com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource' will not stream any tweets. I have moved all the jars to the Flume lib directory and went back to the original TwitterSource. It still streams away without filtering for keywords.

Comment: Hmm. I'd have to re-download the Cloudera VM to test it out myself.

Comment: I'm not using Cloudera - I'm using Google Cloud VMs with Hortonworks installed.

Comment: Same idea. I don't have a working Flume installation at the moment.